# Consuming exactly one file per micro batch in spark stream

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am  new to spark streaming technology and doing a POC to migrate one of our ETL application to spark from commercial ETL tool. We get many small files thorough out the day as INPUT  and will do the ETL operation on that.

As part of POC, we are trying out spark streaming. Currently, we are struck in logic to generate Surrogate KEY values for each record and we identified ROW_NUMBER as the way to generate SK, but it doesn't work for spark stream, as it has to be windowed operation.

I am trying to use the record number column (sequence number for each record in side the files) to generate SK.

1. Consume exactly one file at each micro batch.
2. calculate Sk = Previous batch max record number + record number
3. In write stream phase -calculate and store the max record number value using "foreachbatch" option.

I have used "maxFilesPerTrigger" option to fetch one file, but it doesn't guarantee exactly one file per micro batch.

```
val smsfDF_stream = spark.readStream.option("sep", ",").schema(schema).option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1).option("cleanSource","archive").option("sourceArchiveDir", "/edw_ab_data/spark_poc/archive").csv("/edw_ab_data/spark_poc/input")
```

Also, I see max value for each batchdf, I see '9999' as value

```
val fin_query = resinterdf2.writeStream.format("csv").foreachBatch( (batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long ) => {
    batchDF.createOrReplaceTempView("batchdf_tab") 
    val file_name = "max_file_"+batchId+".dat"
    val max_rec_id = batchDF.sparkSession.sql("""select max(rec_number) from batchdf_tab""")
    max_rec_id.write.format("csv").mode("overwrite").save("/edw_ab_data/spark_poc/max_val.dat")}).option("checkpointLocation", "/edw_ab_data/spark_poc").outputMode("append").option("path", "/edw_ab_data/spark_poc/output").start()
```

Comment: Could you explain what you are actually trying to achieve? Just writing put max record numbers does not sound like a proper ETL use case. Reading your code and trying to understand what your intentions are gives me the impression that you are about to solve an XY problem.

Comment: Actually , I am trying to generate surrogate KEY value for each transaction .In case of batch batch processing , I was able to use below command in spark sql to generate   SK , but spark stream doesn't allow this: ***select row_number() over (order by rec_number,log_time, sp_id, a_addr, b_addr, msg_status  ) network_activity_id***..So , I am traying to generate Surrogate ids based on record number column present in the file , which is sequence number for the record in the file.